# git clone --mirror: since which git version

Tags: git, clone, mirror

Since which git version is it possible to to do `git clone --mirror`?

Searching for "git version history" did not really get the right results...

Comment: Why do you need to know? If your version of git doesn't have it, upgrade. Otherwise, you're fine.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'd need to know which is the least version to upgrade to, as we seem to have a "don't upgrade, don't break anything" policy.

Comment: My suggestion is use the latest release version you can find officially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [git 1.6.0 changelog](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/8/17/174), it was added in version 1.6.0:

> - "git-clone --mirror" is a handy way to set up a bare mirror repository.

Comment: Thank you a lot! How did you find that so fast?

Comment: A quick Google for the term and the word changelog. :)